# Windows doesn't boot anymore after partition change

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning, fdisk, ntfsresize

Background: I normally use Linux as OS. I had a dual boot with Windows XP. Since I had some problems with the windows partition (too long to explain), I shifted it of a while. This is what I have done:

1. resized the filesystem with `ntfsresize -s idontrememberthenewsize /dev/sda3`
2. rebooted the system and checked that windows boots normally
3. backed up the partition with `dd if=/dev/sda3 of=~/win.img`
4. using fdisk, I deleted the old partition and recreated it, restoring its id and boot flag. Now windows partition is `/dev/sda8`:

   ```
    $ fdisk -l

    Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
    Disk identifier: xxx

       Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sda1            2048      616447      307200   83  Linux
    /dev/sda2          616448  3907028991  1953206272    5  Extended
    /dev/sda5          618496    17395711     8388608   82  Linux swap / Solaris
    /dev/sda6        17397760    78837759    30720000   83  Linux
    /dev/sda7        78839808  3702228991  1811694592   83  Linux
    /dev/sda8   *  3702231040  3907028991   102398976    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
   ```
5. restored the partition image with `dd if=~/win.img of=/dev/sda8`
6. `sudo update-grub`
7. changed the partition number to "5" in the `boot.ini` file of the windows partition (read [here](http://www.terabyteunlimited.com/kb/article.php?id=159) for more info)

I also tried other partition numbers, from 1 to 8, but nothing. Only a black screen with the blinking text cursor at top-left is displayed.

Comment: Boot to recovery console and repair boot? If you move the system to another partition, NTLDR needs to know about this.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: I tried with `fixboot c:`, but it doesn't work. `bootcfg /rebuild` gives me the error `Failed to add the selected boot entry`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, I forgot that Windows XP must reside on a primary partition. I deleted it, resized the extended partition, recreated it as primary and restored the image.